# Validating file in function and calling it in main and outputing "file is valid" if it is valid

Tags: c++, file, validation, loops, boolean

Far from done but right now I am trying to get this program to ask for file name and store it in string then convert to ifstream and then check if file is valid by calling separate function isValid to check and it will return true if valid and false if not and if it is valid the main function will out "file is valid".  Then it will keep repeating this until exit is entered.  But it returns false every time and I do not know what is wrong.  I will be great-full for any help.

```
# include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

bool isValid(ifstream& file)
{
    if (file.good())
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



int main()
{
    string file_name;
    cout <<"please enter a HTML file name or hit 'exit' to quit and if you want to clear file please enter 'clear': ";
    cin >> file_name;
    ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());



    while (file_name != "exit")
    {
        if ((isValid(my_file)) == true)
        {
            cout << "Hello" << endl;
        }
        string file_name;
        cout <<"please enter a HTML file name or hit 'exit' to quit and if you want to clear file please enter 'clear': ";
        cin >> file_name;
        ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a problem called "shadowing".

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0) {
        int i = 1;  // declares a new variable that
        // "shadows" (obscures) the outer i inside this scope
    }  // shadow i goes away, original i returns
}
```

The above code will run for ever, because `i` in the context of the while loop is the `i` declared in main.

Your code does this:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());

    while (file_name != "exit")
    {
        if ((isValid(my_file)) == true)  // << outer my_file
        // ...
        ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str()); // << scope-local variable
    }  // << scope local my_file goes away
}
```

You might want to consider refactoring your code to avoid duplication and simplify it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    for (;;) {  // infinite loop
        std::string file_name;
        std::cout <<"please enter a HTML file name or hit 'exit' to quit and if you want to clear file please enter 'clear': " << std::flush;
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, file_name))
            break;
        if (file_name == "exit")
            break;

        std::ifstream my_file(file_name);
        if (!my_file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "unable to open file " << file_name << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to you to re-introduce your isValid function.